# What Can I Do With US Laptop's Power Plug's Ground Pin?

Tags: power-supply, adapter, sockets, ground

DELL Latitude E6420 that i have got in USA has this plug:

[image]

While i have these 2 UK adapters:

[image]

Usually neutral and live fit, but ground pin creates here a problem as the plug won't fit into israeli sockets here.

**UPDATE:** Since i also need traveler's adapter, i think i would better buy one universal adapter instead of power cable so i can kill 2 birds with 1 stone. Unless using traveler's adapter at your home is less recommended than simply buying appropriate cable?

[image]

Here is one **with USB** which is good for charging smartphone or mini-capsule speaker:

[image]

Comment: Why not just buy another proper power cable ENTIRELY? No need for an adapter...

Comment: Picture of the israeli socket please....http://www.walkabouttravelgear.com/13G.htm

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Dell power adapters are designed so that all you need to replace is the cord from the converter to the wall.  Cheap fix.  Contact Dell.

Comment: @Shinrai I also happen to be needing traveler's power adapter.

Comment: @Will So DELL does not recommend using traveler's power adapter but instead better buy power cable?

Comment: @Boris_yo: You need... to ask DELL what it recommends.

Comment: @DELL Hello, i would like to know if running laptop on universal power adapter is safe? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There's a reason the ground pin is positioned there .. exactly to prevent plugging into this type of adapter.

Get an adapter plug which brings out the ground and allows you to connect the ground to the socket in some manner (if you have a 2-pin socket only).

Comment: Do you know if constantly running laptop on traveler's universal power adapter in my home country is technically safe for laptop? Is it better to buy additional power cable or use traveler's universal adapter?

Comment: @Boris_yo, he is stating that it is needed. It is, without it you are not grounding your chassis, this means a fault inside could charge your case and endanger your life.

Comment: @Kortuk What case?

Comment: @Boris_yo, your computer, probably, has a mostly metal case that forms the outside of your PC. The think you have to open to access the guts of your computer. This forms shielding for your PC to outside interference and forms shielding for the outside world from your internal components generating interference.

Comment: @Kortuk I have laptop, not desktop.

Comment: @Boris_yo, i missunderstood an earlier comment from you, it still has an internal metal structure for emissions, almost all do.

Comment: Universal adapter does not have grounding. It has fault protection so if something goes wrong, it is adapter that will take the hit.

Answer (score 2):

Get another cable to connect to the adaptor, from eBay or similar.  They cost very little.

By the way, those are not UK adaptors - they look like Euro-plug adaptors.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an adapter to which you can insert all 3 pins and/or have 3 out pins.

A link to zap were you can find something cheap in Israel: [Zap](http://www.zap.co.il/search.aspx?keyword=%u05EA%u05E7%u05E2%20%u05D0%u05DE%u05E8%u05D9%u05E7%u05D0%u05D9)

Other examples: [Link 1](http://www.ecrater.com/p/11173907/wonpro-wa-15-universal-to-israel-rectangular), [Link 2](http://www.adaptelec.com/wa14-travel-plug-adapter-for-israel-palestine-type-h-si-32-round-pins-p-10.html)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation - get a cable such as [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10228&cs_id=1022807&p_id=7692&seq=1&format=2).  It plugs into your Dell's power brick on one side, but into the local power jack on the other.  Just make sure that your brick is able to handle international power standars (most do).

Comment: This cable is for desktop PCs.

Comment: @Boris_yo - Some high-wattage laptop power supplies use this standard grounded power cable rather than the wussier ungrounded one.  In fact, the fact that you picture a grounded cable end IMPLIES that it's using this one.  I would have assumed the same thing.

Comment: @Shinrai Which cable are you referring to? The one in link that user lacqui posted above? If yes then this is EU ungrounded cable and i need grounded cable.

Comment: @Boris_yo - I am referring to the very first picture you posted in your question.  Seeing that, I would respond exactly like lacqui did, since this is the equivalent cable to the one you pictured.  It is grounded, not ungrounded - the ground is on the OUTLET and fits into the empty plug.  Also, in what world are ungrounded cables "for desktop PCs"?

Comment: Okay it is grounded but in Israel, outlets there are H-type and have entry for grounded pin on plugs unlike E-type outlet where grounded pin protrudes from outlet itself.